# Change Behavior of form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, anchor, modal-dialog

I am using a basic form on my homepage, which collects the users email address. There is NO Submit button, but rather an anchor link which launches a modal box. (the email address the user entered is used in the modal content)

When the user fills in the form email input, their natural instinct is to press enter OR click the "submit" link. The submit link works great by launching the modal, BUT pressing enter will try and submit the form. I DO NOT want the user to submit the form, but rather launch the modal by pressing the anchor link.

**Is there any way to:**

A) Change the default behavior of enter to launch the modal versus submitting the form?

or

B) Disable the Enter button from submitting the form and force the user to click on the anchor link?

---

I am using [leanmodal](http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/?#) which is extremely simple, syntax below:

```
<a href="#newsForm" rel="leanModal" class="submitModal">Submit</a>

<div id="#newsForm">Modal content here</div>
```

***note:** I cannot use the submit input as the "modal launcher" because the modal is not compatible with inputs.*

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather recommend something like this.

```
$(function() {
    $('#newsForm').submit(function( jqEvt ) {
        jqEvt.preventDefault();
        $('.submitModal').click();
    });
});
```

Comment: this is the same as Option C on @OscarJara's answer. On Enter, it still submits the form and brings the user to the top of the page, because this is no action....

Comment: @JCHASE11 Consider that I posted my answer before Oscar Jara even updated his to even include Option C.

Answer (score 0):

**A)** Change the default behavior of enter to launch the modal versus submitting the form:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
            //If user press enter will open the modal
            $('.submitModal').click();
        }
    });
});​
```

**B)** Disable the Enter button from submitting the form and force the user to click on the anchor link.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
            //Stop the "submit", nothing will happen when user press enter
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});​
```

**C) Another alternative:** You can "override" the `submit();` function by doing this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#newsForm').submit(function(e) {
        $('.submitModal').click();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Both Option A & C sound great; although when I try typing in my email and press enter, it still submits the form, and does not launch the modal. You can try it out here on the stay in touch area in the top footer:  http://bajdesign.com/foundationsource/get-started/

Comment: Shouldn't Option C do the same as option A - it disables the submission with preventDefault, and launches the modal with the click??? That is what should be happening but is not.

Comment: @JCHASE11 Why do you have input type submit for your search? I think changing the type to button and doing something extra to submit the search will fix the problem with your modal

Comment: This isn't for the search, this is for the newsletter submit on the bottom of the page. There actually is no input type=submit for this form, as it is replaced by an anchor. Thoughts?

Comment: @JCHASE11 If you check the elements in your browser using chrome console, you will find an input type submit for the searchform. Well, I am making you an example, just wait

Comment: Yes, there is an input type submit for the top search form....SO im guessing when the user presses enter, it will submit the first form in the DOM? Do you think the best bet is to just disable submitting the form by enter site-wide?

Comment: @JCHASE11 Yes, it submits or gets fired for some reason. Your solutions can be: 1) Check what is happening with that submit (why it fires?) 2) Change the input type submit from searchForm to button if you don't find the answer (Also this means that you have to make some jquery get maybe to replace the submit function) 3) Capture when user press enter and fire the modal. Check my example: http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/NeeV7/1/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15073/discussion-between-jchase11-and-oscar-jara)